# Sympy does not simplify square root of natural square numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

When entering

```
sympy.simplify(sympy.sqrt(3)/3)
```

it returns: *sqrt(3)/3* instead of *1/sqrt(3)*
How can I get the simplified expression?
Especially with larger numbers that would be very useful.

```
sympy.simplify(3/sympy.sqrt(3))
```

works, so I assume it prioritizes to remove roots from the denominator? How can I change that?

Comment: You'll notice that it prioritizes to put roots in the numerator, always. I don't know how to fix that but just pointing out that observation.

Comment: Some people, including me, consider `sqrt(3)/3` to be simpler form than `1/sqrt(3)`. Rational denominators are good to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `sympy` uses symbolic stuff, it's printed as `sqrt(3) / 3` just as an output format; internally, `sqrt(3) / 3` is no different from `1 / sqrt(3)`. So computationally, there's not really a difference.

If you want to display it flipped, you can try squaring the top and bottom, representing it as numerator and denominator, and then square root them individually, like so:

```
def stringify(frac):
    if frac<0:
        sign_str = "-"
    else:
        sign_str = ""
    frac = frac ** 2
    numer, denom = frac.as_numer_denom()
    return sign_str + str(sympy.sqrt(numer)) + "/" + str(sympy.sqrt(denom))
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##XY69DsIwDITn@imsTnGLWoluSDxLVdEUMuQHxx3y9KEJDMDik7472xeSPLybcjY2eBaMyYYEsPFyE@MdXt9kiE8WNRGOOAGsesMobNzdbEmVLF2gKXrkq3QdnqFxu9V8wlU7bz/OsMS54rlSRdCwlp1dOai@ftUQEfbYju0x/@y6TQQQjhqiftuU5kQ5vwA)

Answer (score 1):

You might try experiment with the following:

```
>>> def isurd(eq):
...     s = [p for p in eq.atoms(Pow) if p.exp is S.Half and p.base.is_Integer]
...     d = {}
...     reps = {}
...     for p in s:
...         q = Dummy()
...         d[q] = sqrt(p.base)
...         reps[p] = p.base/q
...     rv = eq.xreplace(reps)
...     with evaluate(False):
...         return rv.xreplace(d)
>>> isurd(1/sqrt(32))
1/(4*sqrt(2))
```

Comment: If you mean that it only works for sqrt having a positive value, yes. But if you can do your computation/definitions inside of the `evaluate=False` context, then it will leave negative args alone, too: `with evaluate(False): 1/sqrt(-2)`